# Character * in dynamic import

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Good morning everyone, I have a project with the following structure:

```
intranet
├── modulos
│   ├── almacen
│   │   ├── views
│   │   └── route
│   │       └── index.js
│   │
│   ├── ventas
│   │   ├── views
│   │   └── route
│   │       └── index.js
│   │
│   └── compras
│       ├── views
│       ├── route
│       └── index.js
│
├── route
│   └── index.js
├── store
│   └── index.js
├── ...
```

The modules folder will have all the modules that I will be connecting to the project, the point is that all the subfolders will have the views, route, etc. subfolders. In turn, in the route folder there will always be an index.js file.

Now in the intranet > route > index file I want to do the import as follows.

```
import("../modulos/*/route/index").then(module => {
    console.log(module);
});
```

This in order to carry out a self-import of those modules that it finds. The problem is that I get an error because apparently the character * (asterisk) is not allowed inside the import.

I will appreciate the help you give me. Thank you.

Comment: If you're using Vue with Webpack, I would check out require.context(...). We're build an application with the convention-over-configuration pattern. Route descriptors in .route.ts files, filters in .filter.ts files, store modules in .store.ts files etc...

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible you have to iterate over all directories in 'modulos'

```js
// pseudo code
for(const folder in modulos_subfolders) {
    import(``../modulos/${folder}/route/index`)
}
```